# how to use log in ir

Tags: math

I am sorry if this question sounds dumb.

Why does [inverse document frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) use log? How does log help in tf/idf?

Comment: I'd recommend removing c# and java tags from this question as this question isn't specific to either language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, Using a log helps normalise numbers with a geometric distribution e.g. 1 in 100, and 1 in 1000000 become 2 and 6 which are conceptually easier to manage.

Similar uses are in noise levels (db) and seismic energy (i.e. richter scale)

How does this question related to Java, C# or data-structures?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Mostly people use Java, C or C# to implement TF/IDF, that is why I invited these people to read and answer this question.